# The AWS Lambda returns "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT **.****.***.***:443"

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, aws-lambda

I have to services, Admin Panel(Laravel) и Online Shop(Woocommerce). The relation between these to services was realized with **AWS Lambda**.

When I try to send an updating product request from my Admin panel to online shop, time to time the lambda couldn't connect to the Woocomerce API.

On time when the system is not updating the product, lambda returns the error "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT"

I originally thought that the Wordpress didn't have enought time for updating process. And decided to increase the lambda's timeout (60000 ms). But it didn't help. I still found the ETIMEDOUT errors in logs.

By the way, the time period between sending the updating request to woocommerce and showing an error is 2 min. If I right understand, the lambda had enough time for getting the answer from woocommerce.

Another strange thing. According the lambda's logs, on time when lambda got an error, the woocommerce API was available. It seems like something disconnects the internet on time when lambda is sending the request.

My question is, why lambda cannot send to Woocommerce API the request. Why it happens time to time?

P.S. Below I added the example of lambda's logs.

The log on starting sending the updating request.

```
2021-08-14T18:23:48.692Z    b228455b-45a8-5cbf-8160-1cc INFO    Inside edit Online List {
  status: '1',
  *********
  is_delete: 0,
  name: 'Omega Speedmaster Moonwatch Chronograph 42mm ',
  price_on_request: 0,
  on_sale: 0
 }
```

The log with error.

```
2021-08-14T18:25:58.299Z    b228455b-45a8-5cbf-8aae6    INFO    WooCommerce editOnlineStock err::: { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ***.****.***.***:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '***.****.***.***',
  port: 443,
  config:
   { url:
      'https://domain/wp-json/wc/v3/products/*****',
     method: 'put',
     params: {},
     data:
      '{"name":"Omega Speedmaster Moonwatch Chronograph 42mm ","type":"simple"***********',
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'WooCommerce REST API - JS Client/1.0.1',
        'Content-Length': 681 },
     auth:
      { username: 'ck_************',
        password: 'cs_************' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 60000,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     responseType: 'json',
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     ****************************
```

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to run within your VPC?

Answer (score 1):

Is your lambda associated with a VPC? If so, i) explore to see if the VPC has a route out to the internet with a NAT gateway/instance, ii) examine the VPC flow logs for errors.